# using backreferences regex in sed

Tags: regex, unix, sed, ksh, aix

I would like to remove multiple spaces in a file with a single character.
Example

```
cat      kill    rat
dog      kill    cat
```

I used the following regex, which seemed to matched in http://www.regexpal.com/ but wasn't working in sed.

```
([^ ])*([ ])*
```

I used the sed command like so:

```
sed s/\(\[\^\ \]\)*\(\[\ \]\)*/\$1\|/g < inputfile
```

I expect,

```
cat|kill|rat
dog|kill|cat
```

But I couldn't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
kindly note that cat/dog could be any character than whitespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` backreferences with backslashes, so use \1 instead of $1.
Surround your expressions with quotes:

```
sed 's/match/replace/g' < inputfile
```

Manpages are the best invention in Linux world: [`man sed`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sed)

Watch out for `*`, it can actually match NOTHING.
If you want to replace multiple spaces with a '|', use this RE:

```
sed -r 's/ +/\|/g'
```

From `man sed`:

```
-r, --regexp-extended
   use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

You don't need any backreferences if you just want to replace all spaces.
Replace  (space) by `\s` if you want to match tabs too.

Comment: Thanks. But regex doesn't work correctly. Why does \1 matches every character and not the strings "cat" "dog"

Comment: because you're using `*`, which can match nothing. See my edited answer.

Comment: From `man sed` for the `--regexp-extended` switch: `for portability use POSIX -E`

Comment: Are backreferences supported by POSIX sed? EDIT: Yes, they are: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html "The characters `\n`, where n is a digit, shall be replaced by the text matched by the corresponding back-reference expression."

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sed -e 's/[[:blank:] ]/\|/g ' < inputfile
```

whete `[:blank:]` is space and tab characters

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP wanted with `sed` and that the question is old, but what about `tr -s ' ' input`?

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
s/\s+/\|/g
```